# Proving $\sum_{k=-N}^N e^{ik θ} = \frac{\sin[(N+1/2) θ]}{\sin(θ/2)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I cannot figure out how to prove this trigonometric identity.

$$\sum_{k=-N}^N e^{ik θ} = \frac{\sin[(N+1/2) θ]}{\sin(θ/2)}$$

I considered using the formula of a geometric sum, but that didn’t give me the desired output.

Comment: It is enough to consider the sum from zero to $N$.

Comment: Set $e^{i \theta} = q$ and use the sum formula 
$$\sum _{n=-m}^m q^n=\frac{q^{m+1/2}-q^{-m-1/2}}
{q^{1/2}- q^{-1/2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*} \sum_{k=-N}^N e^{ik\theta} & = e^{-iN\theta}\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1} e^{ik\theta}=e^{-iN\theta}\cdot\frac{e^{i(2N+2)\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\frac{e^{i(N+1)\theta}-e^{-iN\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-1} \\ & =\frac{e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{-i\theta/2}}\cdot \frac{e^{i(N+1)\theta}-e^{-iN\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\frac{e^{i(N+1/2)\theta}-e^{-i(N+1/2)\theta}}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}}\\&=\frac{e^{i(N+1/2)\theta}-e^{-i(N+1/2)\theta}}{2i}\cdot\frac{2i}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}}\\&=\frac{\sin((N+1/2)\theta)}{\sin(\theta/2)}.\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \sum_{k=-N}^N e^{i k \theta} 
= & \frac{e^{-i N \theta}\left(e^{i(2 N+1) \theta}-1\right)}{e^{i \theta}-1} \\
= & \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} i \theta}\left(e^{i\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta}-e^{-i\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta}\right)}{e^{\frac{1}{2} i \theta}\left(e^{\frac{1}{2} i \theta}-e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \theta}\right)} \\
= & \frac{2 i \sin \left[\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta\right]}{2 i \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)} \\
= & \frac{\sin \left[\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta\right]}{\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$